# Use meta query only 3 or more results?

Tags: wp-query, query, meta-query

Using elementor I'm currently running the following:

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/model-query', function( $query ) {
    $meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );

    $meta_query = array();
    
    global $post;
    $post_slug = $post->post_name;
    
    $pieces = explode('-', $post_slug);
    $last_word = array_pop($pieces);
        
    $meta_query[] = [
        'key' => 'car_makemodel',
        'value' => $last_word,
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ];
    
    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );

} );
```

Which is correctly searching the car_makemodel field for the car make in the page slug and returning the posts with cars of that make, however, I would like to only run the meta query if 3 or more results exist, if possible. I'm not sure where to start on adding that second part though as I assume this is just looking at the meta query rather than executing the full query?

Comment: Well you can't know how many exist until you've run some sort of query already... ...so instead you would determine in your output code (which I don't see above) whether or not to display anything based on whether or not 3 or more results are returned.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use "count" ?

```
$cars=array("Ford","Chevy","BMW");
echo count($cars);
```

The above would give a count of "3"

So in your code, count the number in the query array and IF greater than "X" then return the query.